# How to navigate from one view to another view in single viewcontroller in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller

May somebody let me know:
How to navigate from one view to another view in single viewcontroller in iphone sdk? I have an application in which i want to push to next view and pop to previous view in a single View controller. How this functionality can be achieved?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure you can use navigation controller to navigate views into single view controller, indeed in self.myNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController]; you have to pass a view controller to the init not a view

Comment: For that you have add Navigation controller through AppDelegate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the solution for this problem and here is the solution as below:-

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    IBOutlet UIButton *backbtn;
    IBOutlet UIButton *nxtBtn;
    IBOutlet UILabel *label;
}
-(IBAction)nxt:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)ba:(id)sender;

@end

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@end

int count=0;

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    label.text=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"NavigtionNumber"];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}
-(IBAction)nxt:(id)sender
{
    count++;
    label.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@" navigation time %d",count];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:label.text forKey:@"NavigtionNumber"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    ViewController *vc=[[ViewController alloc] init];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];

}

-(IBAction)ba:(id)sender
{
    count--;
    label.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@" navigation time %d",count];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:label.text forKey:@"NavigtionNumber"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}


- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

@end
```

Hope this will help others in future.

Thanks.

Comment: ok, but here you don't navigate trough 2 view inside a single view controller, you use 2 instance of the same view controller one declared inside another, and this pushed and popped... cool way anyway, but pheraps can be useful change a bit the question

Comment: i guess you can change viewController in the above code and so change view, of course my mistake.... buddy :)

Comment: Bad approach to push and pop same viewcontroller, instead you can change layouts dude...

Comment: Buddy i did the same in my application and this work fine as this reduce the size of the application and we can perform multiple functionality in a single class.

Comment: do you know which things increase your app size?

Answer (score 2):

You can add and remove your secondview.Like this to navigate

```
-(IBAction)navigate:(id)sender
{
  [self.view addSubView:secondView];
}
```

and this one to po to first view

```
-(IBAction)popToFirstView:(id)sender
{
  [secondView removeFromSuperView];
}
```

Note:- You can use animations for adding and removing view, if you want to give animated effects.

Comment: i want to use Navigation controller in single View controller

Answer (score 1):

If you need a single view controller you can try using a UIScrollView, that contain the 2 view, and a button to scroll from a view to another... but if i can give a tip, it's better using 2 view controller and a navigation view controller

Comment: i want to use Navigation controller in single View controller and navigate Views

Answer (score 1):

You need to use UINavigation Controller to get push and pop.

do this way

In **AppDelegate.h** file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
//this will be your first screen
@property (strong, nonatomic) FavViewController *favViewController;

@end
```

In A**ppDelegate.m** file

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "FavViewController.h"


@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize favViewController;

    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {
        self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]]; 

        //initialize view controller
        favViewController = [[FavViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FavViewController" bundle:nil];

       //add navigation controller
        UINavigationController *favouriteView = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:favViewController];  


       //add controller to witndow
        self.window.rootViewController = favouriteView;   
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];    

        return YES;
    }

@end
```

Now come to the **UIViewController**, where you want to load/push to new controller

**to load/push to new controller** use this code

```
//this will be next screen
DetailsViewController *detailsViewController = [[DetailsViewController alloc ]init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailsViewController animated:YES];
```

to **go back or pop controller use this**

```
//now it will send back to parent screen
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```